# CSS vertical tab headings | Jquery not displaying content when tabs heading is clicked [Rails 4 & Jquery UI]

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

Hi i am currently new to ruby on rails & JqueryUI. i am trying to create a vertical tab. when a tab is clicked the specific content under the tab is displayed. I used the example from the Jquery **website**: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#vertical except i structured it slightly to suit my coding. in my HTML file, i have created 3columns - 'left-colum', 'middle-column & 'right-colum'. [i have 3 tabs] I have situated the 3tabs in the 'left-column', when the 1st tab is clicked the content for the 1st tab will be displayed within the 'middle-column'

**Question: when a tab is clicked, for example tab1 - how do i get only the contents for tab 1 to be displayed using CSS & JqueryUI**

**HTML: views/layouts/application.html.erb**. I added the script: `# src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js">`

```
<head>
  <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
```

**HTML: views/users/show.html.erb**

```
<div class="left-column">
  <h3>left-column</h3>
  <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-1">My Discussions</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-2">My Blogs</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-3">My Events</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="middle-column">
  <h3>middle-column</h3>
  <div id="tabs">
    <div id="tabs-1">
      <h2>My Discussions</h2>
      <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
      <h2>My Blogs</h2>
      <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
      <h2>My events</h2>
        <% if @user.events.any? %>
          <ul><%= render @events %></ul>
        <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="right-bar">
  <h3>right-column</h3>
  <div>
    <div><%= render 'shared/user_followers' %></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS: app/assets/stylesheets/application.css**

```
.ui-tabs-vertical { 
  width: 55em; 
}

.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav { 
  padding: .2em .1em .2em .2em; 
  float: left; width: 12em; 
}

.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li { 
  clear: left; width: 100%; 
  border-bottom-width: 1px !important; 
  border-right-width: 0 !important; 
  margin: 0 -1px .2em 0; 
}

.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li a { 
  display:block; 
}

.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active { 
  padding-bottom: 0; 
  padding-right: .1em; 
  border-right-width: 1px; 
  border-right-width: 1px; 
}

.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-panel { 
  padding: 1em; 
  float: right; 
  width: 40em;
}
```

**Javascrip/JqueryUI: app/assets/stylesheets/application.js**

```
$(function() {
  $( "#tabs" ).tabs().addClass( "ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix" );
  $( "#tabs li" ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-left" );
});
```

Comment: Pretty sure the actual content has to be part of the element that you apply `.tabs()` to, whereas you have it outside of it …

Comment: First of you don't need to add jquery-ui separately. If you didn't make any changes in application.js then it would have been automatically included in your page. Secondly can you make jsfiddle or give us some link where we can see your app?

Comment: Hi @CBore, according to the details in http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#vertical  the content is meant to be part of .tabs(), but would you know how to make it function when the content is placed in a different column [2nd column] with the tab headings in the first column? many thanks